# Proving $H \subseteq K$ & $[G:H]=[G:K] $ $\implies$ $H=K$ , without using extended Lagrange's theorem

Tags: group-theory

Let $H \subseteq K$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $[G:H]=[G:K] $ (finite) , then without using  the

formula $[G:H]=[G:K][K:H]$ , can we prove that $H=K$ ?

Comment: I don't know about extended Lagrange's Theorem, but $[G:H]=o(G)/o(H)$. Hence, $H$ and $G$ have to have the same order. As one is a subset of another, we inevitably have $H=K$. Am I using extended Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: Nowhere it is given that $G$ is finite ; only the indices of the subgroups are finite

Answer (score 1):

Say $H\neq K$. Then there exists an element in $K$ which is not there in $H$. Let that element be $k$. Then $kH\in G/H$ is not equal to identity.

As $G/H$ and $G/K$ are finite, if we can prove the existence of an injective mapping that is not surjective between the two, we can prove that they are not of the same order.

If you put these facts together, you will arrive upon an argument soon enough. Think about the mapping $aK\to aH$